# What is a good practice to wait for context cancel() to complete?

Tags: go, goroutine, go-context

Given I have the program below, what is a good practice to make the method cancelled (`service.Start()`) complete (i.e. printing *Done*) before terminating by calling the `cancel()` function ? I only have a single Go routine so using a `WaitGroup` doesn't feel right. When I comment out the last line (`time.Sleep`) in the `main()` function it seems like the program finishes prematurely, as the `service.Start()` doesn't print *Done*. If I uncomment the 2 second sleep, then *Done* gets printed. I am just trying to find the best practice of achieving the canceled method to complete without terminating the program prematurely, but both using a `WaitGroup` or `time.Sleep()` seem to me as a bad practice for this specific program. The reason I am using a Go routine and an exit channel is because the `service.Start()` will contain logic that needs to run  periodically until the program is stopped.

**main:**

```
func main() {
    log.Infoln("starting service..")
    ctx := context.Background()
    srv := service.Service{}

    exitCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(exitCh, syscall.SIGTERM, // terminate: stopped by `kill -9 PID`
        syscall.SIGINT, // interrupt: stopped by Ctrl + C
    )

    ctxCancel, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    go run(ctxCancel, srv, exitCh)

    <-exitCh // blocking until receive exit signal
    cancel()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
}

func run(ctx context.Context, srv service.Service, exitCh chan<- os.Signal) {
    defer func() {
        exitCh <- syscall.SIGTERM // send terminate signal when application stop naturally
    }()
    err := srv.Start(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Warningf("canceling all operations: %s", err)
    }
}
```

**service:**

```
type Service struct {}

func (s *Service) Start(ctx context.Context) error {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Println("Done")
            return ctx.Err()
        default:
            log.Printf("i value: %d", i)
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You want to wait for the launched goroutines to finish, that's what `WaitGroup` is for. It's to wait for arbitrary number of gorutines, which can be 1, there's absolutely no problem with that. If you choose to use `WaitGroup`, you can easily extend your app to wait for multiple goroutines instead of one in the future. Alternatively you may use a channel, and close it in the goroutine. Or in general, you can use any concurrency-safe construct to signal the completion.